# unfortunately has stopped when I want to update ListView

Tags: java, android

My logic is as follows.
First, I get some data from the server. Then, I manipulate the data. Next, I put the data into a `ListView`. If the user scrolls to the bottom of this view, I want to refresh the view. I copy the properties from my `Async` object to a new object. At this point I see "unfortunately has stopped".

Here my code of activity class

```
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);

            this.Syear  = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            this.Smonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            Smonth = Smonth + 1;
            InboxActivity i = new InboxActivity();

            String user_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString(LoginActivity.SESSION_ID);           

            final FetchTask fetch = new FetchTask();
            fetch.Selectedmonth = this.Smonth;
            fetch.Selectedyear = this.Syear;
            fetch.page = 0;
            fetch.sess_id = user_id;
            ListView ll = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mailList);
            fetch.ll = ll;
            fetch.execute();

            ll.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){



                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
                {
                    if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount==totalItemCount)
                    {

                        //System.out.println("HERE WILL BE MY SESSION ID!!!!w");
                        //System.out.println(fetch.sess_id);

                        FetchTask RefreshFetch = new FetchTask();

                        fetch.page++;
                        RefreshFetch.page           =  fetch.page++;
                        RefreshFetch.Selectedmonth  =  fetch.Selectedmonth;
                        RefreshFetch.Selectedyear   =  fetch.Selectedyear;
                        RefreshFetch.sess_id        =  fetch.sess_id;
                        RefreshFetch.ll             =  fetch.ll;

                        RefreshFetch.execute();

                    }                       

                }


            });

        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;    
    }



public class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {

        public JSONArray result_arr;
        public String result_str,email,password,test;
        public int Selectedyear;
        public int Selectedmonth;
        public int page;
        public String sess_id;
        public ListView ll;
        public ProgressDialog pd;
        public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


        @Override

        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("MY SITE URL ....");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);



                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qw", "das"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("debug", "1"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("t", "0"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m", Integer.toString(this.Selectedmonth)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("y", Integer.toString(this.Selectedyear)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st", Integer.toString(this.page)));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sess_id", this.sess_id));


                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine());
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                String result11 = sb.toString();

                this.result_str = result11;
                // parsing data
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result11);





                return new JSONArray(result11);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }



          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {

          }
```

My logs

```
03-05 13:24:43.239: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 7% free 3326K/3540K, paused 33ms, total 35ms
03-05 13:24:43.629: D/gralloc_goldfish(2052): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-05 13:24:50.349: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 151K, 8% free 3690K/4004K, paused 28ms, total 36ms
03-05 13:24:50.349: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(2052): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
03-05 13:24:50.349: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(2052):   in android.widget.EditText{b1e53a20 VFED..CL .F....I. 179,489-589,548 #7f090004 app:id/password}
03-05 13:24:50.349: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(2052):   0: sent at 11916532000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=11916532, downTime=11916440, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
03-05 13:24:55.809: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 417K, 14% free 3788K/4368K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
03-05 13:24:56.509: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 12% free 3877K/4368K, paused 39ms, total 42ms
03-05 13:24:56.549: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28K, 12% free 3947K/4468K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
03-05 13:24:56.599: I/dalvikvm-heap(2052): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.087MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-05 13:24:56.649: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 5048K/5572K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
03-05 13:25:14.239: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 504K, 12% free 5273K/5940K, paused 56ms, total 58ms
03-05 13:25:15.319: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 125 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:15.809: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:16.209: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:17.249: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:17.599: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:22.239: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:22.659: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:23.629: I/Choreographer(2052): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 13:25:24.819: D/AndroidRuntime(2052): Shutting down VM
03-05 13:25:24.819: W/dalvikvm(2052): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aefba8)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): Process: com.example.earchive, PID: 2052
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.example.earchive.InboxActivity$FetchTask.onPostExecute(InboxActivity.java:291)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.example.earchive.InboxActivity$FetchTask.onPostExecute(InboxActivity.java:1)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-05 13:25:24.919: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 13:25:26.259: D/dalvikvm(2052): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 385K, 9% free 5692K/6240K, paused 145ms, total 145ms
```

On post execute method

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result)
{
    if (result != null) 
    {
        List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                emails.add(json_data.getString("mittente"));
                subjects.add(json_data.getString("oggetto"));
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        if(this.page == 0)
        {
            this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    InboxActivity.this,
                    R.layout.da_item,
                    emails
                );
            this.ll.setAdapter(this.adapter);               
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
            { 
                JSONObject json_data;
                try 
                {
                    json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    this.adapter.add(json_data.getString("mittente"));  
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Messages not found");

    }    
    this.pd.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Post logcat output as well.

Comment: i'v done it check it please

Comment: I tried to salvage the introductory paragraph, but it was so hard to understand that I may have made a mistake. I apologize if my interpretation was poor. Can you please narrow down the code to only the portions that are relevant? You shouldn't post your entire program on Stack and expect us to look through all of it.

Comment: NullPointerException on line 291. That's what is causing it to crash. Don't listen to John, more code is better.

Comment: Spidy, my 291 line is :
 `this.adapter.add(json_data.getString("mittente"));`

Comment: do u have onPostExecute method in asynctask??

Comment: Yes, i updated  check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this.adapter.add(json_data.getString("mittente"));` is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

If ***page = 1***, `this.adapter` is not initialized (***page = 0***) and is therefore NULL. If page 0 is guaranteed to be called before page 1, this would work, but I'm guessing it is not. Here's a fix if I understand your code correctly.

```
    if( this.adapter == null ) {
            this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                InboxActivity.this,
                R.layout.da_item,
                emails
            );
        this.ll.setAdapter(this.adapter);
    }
    if(this.page != 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
        { 
            JSONObject json_data;
            try 
            {
                json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                this.adapter.add(json_data.getString("mittente"));  
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```